# B-tree minimum internal children count explanation

Tags: b-tree

Why does B-tree must have internal children count of ceil(m/2) - 1.
I have searched it, but there isn't any explanation for that.

Answer (score 0):

That is not exactly true, and what is true is part of the definition.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)

> According to Knuth's definition, a B-tree of order m is a tree which satisfies the following properties:
>
> 1. Every node has at most m children.
> 2. Every non-leaf node (except root) has at least ⌈m/2⌉ child nodes.
> 3. The root has at least two children if it is not a leaf node.
> 4. A non-leaf node with k children contains k − 1 keys.
> 5. All leaves appear in the same level and carry no information.

So it is not `ceil(m/2)`, but `ceil(m/2)`...`m`, and it is not granted but achieved, it is a goal.

---

The purpose is to maintain a minimum density of storage. "Too empty" nodes waste space. So technically when deleting you could go down to a single child, and that would be a working tree construct (even a linked list is still a valid graph after all), just that would waste a lot.

The `m/2` thing itself comes from node splitting. When a full node is split into two, you will have a `floor(m/2)` and a `ceil(m/2)` node (if `m` is even, the two are the same), and the new entry is added to the smaller one. Then both becomes something greater or equal to `ceil(m/2)`.

- even case: `m=4`, `m/2=2=ceil(m/2)=floor(m/2)`, results after adding new entry are `2` and `3`, both `>=2`
- odd case: `m=5`, `ceil(m/2)=3`, `floor(m/2)=2`, the latter gets new entry, they become `3` and `3`, both `>=3`.

Comment: My question is that, why is desing goal ceil(m/2) - 1, what is the purpose of it?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some additional considerations that may be helpful.

The '`m/2` thing' is only set in stone if you refer to a specific academic definition of B-tree, like e.g. Donald Knuth's `ceil(m/2)` definition. If you want to talk about B-trees in general instead then pretty much anything goes.

For example, among the definitions that are based on counting slots - keys or pointers, as the case may be - there is another one by Donald Knuth that decrees a minimum fill factor of 2/3 and which is often referred to as B*tree. A split turns two neighbouring nodes into three and a merge takes three nodes to make two. Such a B-tree has a higher average occupancy (fill factor) than a classic `m/2` B-tree.

Practical B-trees tend to base their restrictions on more practical things. For example, many production-grade implementations use pages of a fixed size like 4 KB or 8 KB, and hence they tend to base their occupancy restrictions on the actual space used in a node/page instead of counting filled slots. They may defer the rebalancing to a later time or to a background process in order to reduce the impact of locking on performance under concurrent usage, thus allowing even completely empty nodes/pages to exist for some time.